# Javascript animation not showing one after the other

Tags: javascript, loops, css-animations, settimeout

I'm not an expert in javascript and this might be pretty straightforward but I would really appreciate some help. I am trying to show each menu item one after the other with a little animation. Those elements are hidden for another reason so I have to unhide them as well. For the moment all i get is one animation for all the elements:

```
            for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                setTimeout(function(){   
                    setTimeout(function(){   
                        document.getElementById('sm-menu-'+i).classList.add('fadeinfrombottom');
                        document.getElementById('sm-menu-'+i).classList.remove('d-none');     
                        }, 100);  
                    }, 700);
            }
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that all timeout functions starts at the same time

you can try using different delays like this

```js
function current() {

  console.log('start')
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
    }, 1000)
  }
}

function newImplementation() {

  console.log('start')
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
    }, 1000 * i)
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button id="current" onclick="current()"> Current implementation</div>
<div><button onclick="newImplementation()"> new implementation</div>
```